# Configure Always On for publisher

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, transactional-replication

We have a pull transaction replication.Publisher runs MSSQL 2016. 
Distributer runs on separate server with MSSQL 2016. 
Is it possible to define Always On over publisher and another new server, so that publisher will become the primary in AG. 
Most important that subscribers will keep going.
We are ok with disabling replication for several hours, but we would like to keep it without recreating.
(I could only find articles on defining replication above Always ON, which is the contrary of my request)

Comment: In order for the publisher/subscriber to switch role automatically using Always On Availability Group you have to drop current subscriber and start from section 2 of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) document. You do not have to recreate you publications.

Comment: I mean the publisher and one more new server. I don't want to touch the subscribers at all.

Comment: I still think it should work following from section 2.

Comment: But can I prevent dropping the subscriber ? This is the whole point of my question ??

Comment: I do not know for sure. Since your subscriber is not part of Replica you might. I suggest you test in non production before attempting production.

Comment: Your new server has to be part of AG and then you can follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2014/01/30/setting-up-replication-on-a-database-that-is-part-of-an-alwayson-availability-group/ to setup. Test it in a test/lab environment about certain gotchas.

Comment: We succeeded yesterday to make existing publisher part of AG group without failing the replication